# Expression returning wrong value in QGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes

My QGIS Field Calculator expression:

```
case when "field_value" = '' or  "field_value" <> NULL then (if( "field_value" = '', 'N', 'Y')) end
```

returns null value even if "field_value" has something in it.

Note: "field_value" is in string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited answer)

I think you can safely replace your main condition with `"field_value" is not NULL` (the comparison with `null` is somewhat counter-intuitive):

```
case
  when "field_value" is not null then if( "field_value" = '', 'N', 'Y')
end
```

Comment: I think else is an optional condition and not required.

Comment: this either isn't working.

Comment: @KeshavSharma You're right, I misunderstood your expression. I've edited my answer (and tested it this time...), I think it should work.